# Зачем volatile если есть True/False sharing?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть True и False sharing которые позволяет процессорам обмениваться кэш-линиями. Как при этом может существовать проблема visibility?

Если sharing позволяет ядрам видеть кэши друг друга, то в чем тогда проблема которую решает `volatile`?

Или можно еще перефразировать так: чего не хватает sharing механизмам, чтобы в состоянии контролируемой гонки предотвратить утечку данных?

Возможно, что sharing-то работает, но он работает только для тех процессоров, которые уже имеют данную переменную в кэше, а потоки-новобранцы могут прочитать данные из памяти, которые уже не актуальны, так как те потоки, что уже давно работают с этой переменной — успели изменить ее значение после последней выгрузки в память?

То есть в промежутке между первым считыванием из памяти переменной и её первого  изменения шаринг не срабатывает? (как гипотеза).

**Update:**
*"если протокол согласованности кэшей (cache coherency) обязывает кэши процессора хранить ячейку памяти в согласованном состоянии, то зачем нужен volatile, который делает то же самое?"*

Comment: Я думаю, проблема в том, что это самое false sharing не гарантировано. Переменные вполне могут сидеть на разных кэш-линиях.

Comment: А какой у вас пример со счётчиками? Поскольку volatile недостаточно для безопасного инкремента, проблема может быть как раз в этом.

Comment: @VladD у меня нет конкретного примера но их куча одинаковых понятно что если поставить volatile все будет работать вопрос теоретический заключается именно в недостатках  sharing механизмов которые получается лечат volatile. Сидеть на разных кеш линиях это вы имеете в виду что переменная не помещается в одну кеш линию или что то другое?

Comment: По поводу примера: я имел в виду, что если в двух разных потоках для разделяемой переменной `x` сделать по 1000 раз `x++`, то volatile не поможет гарантировать результат. А по поводу разных кеш-линий, я имел в виду, что переменные, хоть и маленькие, могут не принадлежать одной и той же кеш-линии. Например, одна из них находится в конце кеш-линии, а другая — в начале следующей. При этом false sharing возникать не будет.

Comment: @VladD да пример надо было добавить я имел что инкремент происходит в синхронизированном блоке. Но даже не смотря на синхронизацию известно что volatile необходим так как процессоры кэшируют переменную и чтобы запретить им это мы ставим volatile и неизвестно когда они сделают пуш в память. Но если есть  шаринги то получается потоки видят изменения друг друга. Хотя появилась мысль что это сработает только для тех процессоров которые уже имеют у себя в кэше данную переменную а новоприбывшие потоки не будут знать о ней и прочтут версию из памяти.

Comment: @VladD очевидно в виду имеется следующее: если есть протокол cache coherence, обещающий невозможность чтения невалидных данных из кэша, то что именно обеспечивает volatile (потому что cache coherence обещает примерно то, что описывают при объяснении volatile)?

Comment: @Pavel: «Но даже не смотря на синхронизацию известно что volatile необходим» — ??? Это противоречит вообще всему, что я знаю. Можно какую-нибудь подтверждающую ссылку?

Comment: @etki: Хм. В вопросе ничего вроде бы не сказано о когерентности, так что я не вполне понимаю, как это укладывается в вопрос. // Оффтопик: Ну и какой бы ни был протокол, очевидно, что он оперирует юнитами памяти не более определённого размера (например, размера кеш-линии). Поэтому без дополнительных соображений я не вижу, как любой протокол кеширования сможет гарантировать валидность _произвольно больших_ данных.

Comment: @VladD очевидно, false sharing упомянут именно в том контексте, что если обновилось значение в одном кэше, то и другие каскадно обновятся, выполняя таким образом работу volatile. У меня самого у этому протоколу пока вопросы, я нашел некоторые уточнения на en.so, но ответ пока не готов давать. По поводу "несмотря на синхронизацию volatile необходим" - http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html, конкретный параграф ищется по *monitorexit*.

Comment: @etki: Ну это (DCL) немного другая история: корень проблемы здесь в **чтении** разделяемой переменной `helper` без синхронизации. Если бы чтение было с синхронизацией, никакой volatile не был бы нужен. Так что это пример не на «не смотря на синхронизацию, volatile необходим», а на «при **неполной** синхронизации volatile иногда помогает».

Comment: @etki: «если обновилось значение в одном кэше, то и другие каскадно обновятся» — а, теперь понял. Но в статье о false sharing на википедии «может обновиться», а не «должно обновиться», такшта...

Comment: @VladD то есть false sharing может просто не произойти? Короче говоря гарантий нет тут как повезет.

Comment: @Pavel: Именно так.

Comment: @Pavel: А можно полный пример, в котором утечка без volatile? Потому что для меня код выглядит нормально.

Comment: Мне нравится этот вопрос, с интересом прочитал ответ. Поэтому держите конкурс — немного дополнительного внимания и репы, а может и еще один ответ.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**False Sharing**

False Sharing это термин, описывающий механизм нежелательного снижения производительности, когда разные потоки модифицируют независимые переменные, которые оказались на одной кеш линии.

Прочитайте замечательную [стататью с Хабра](https://habrahabr.ru/company/intel/blog/143446/), где описаны эти механизмы. Если кратко, то вот цитата:

> При этом, если один из потоков модифицирует поле своей структуры, то
>   вся кэш-линия в соответствии с cache coherency протоколом объявляется
>   невалидной для остальных ядер процессора. Другой поток уже не сможет
>   пользоваться своей структурой, несмотря на то, что она уже лежит в L1
>   кэше его ядра. В старых процессорах типа P4 в такой ситуации
>   потребовалась бы долгая синхронизация с основной памятью, то есть
>   модифицированные данные были бы отправлены в основную память и потом
>   считаны в L1 кэш другого ядра.

**Volatile**

Модификатор volatile это ключево слово в языке java, введенное в язык для поддержки безопасного многопоточного программирования. Оно накладывает некоторые дополнительные условия на чтение/запись переменной. Важно понять три вещи о volatile переменных:

1. Операции чтения/записи volatile переменной являются атомарными.
2. Результат операции записи значения в volatile переменную одним потоком, становится виден всем другим потокам, которые используют эту переменную для чтения из нее значения.
3. Ключевое слово volatile запрещает некоторые оптимизации/перестановки в процессоре и/или компиляторе.

Т.е. сравнивать эти понятия не совсем корректно ибо volatile это слово для реализации безопасных многопоточных пограмм, а false sharing это термин описывающий деградацию производительности.

Посмотрите замечательные лекции от Алексея Шипилева по [java memory model](https://shipilev.net/#jmm) (и не только), где он все раскладывает по полочкам.

Если у Вас будут вопросы, то я могу попробовать раскрыть обновляя свой ответ.

UPD: Ответы на вопросы внизу.

> а где в спеке написано что volatile гарантирует нам атомарность
>   операций?

Ссылки: [Essentials от Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html), [спецификация](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4)

> Разве не для того мы ставим synchronize чтобы предотвратить
>   последствия не атомарности? Если бы volatile гарантировал атомарность
>   то он бы один решал все проблемы, так получается или нет?

Важно понять, что существуют два аспекта потокобезопасности: (1) контроль выполнения и (2) видимость памяти. Первый отвечает за контроль выполнения кода (включая порядок инструкций) и разрешая/запрещая некоторым блокам программы возможность выполняться конкурентно (concurrently /одновременно). Второе какие действия с памятью видны или не видны для других потоков. Это вызвано тем, что каждый процессор имеет несколько уровней кеша между самим процессором и общей памятью, поэтому потоки запущенные на разных ядрах процессора могут видеть "разную память" в один и тот же момент из-за локального кеша процессора.

**Synchronized**

Использование `synchronized` не позволяет другому процессу захватить монитор (или lock) **на том же самом обьекте**, таким образом препятствуя конкуррентному (одновременному) выполнению кода, заключенного в synchronized блок. Важно учесть, что синхронизация создает так называемое отношение happens-before. Это отношение позволяет потоку захватившему монитор "увидеть" все изменения, сделанные другим потоком до захвата и отпускания (release) монитора.
На практике же это будет соответствовать (грубое приближение) тому, что процессор будет обновлять кеши в момент захвата монитора и записывать в память после его освобождения. Эти оперции довольно долгие (относительно).

**Volatile**

Ипользование volatile заставляет делать операции с переменной используя память програмы "минуя" кеш процессора. Это может быть полезно, когда нам нужна видимость этой переменной в разных потоках, но при этом нам не важен парядок доступа к данной переменной. Также на 32bit java запись long & double становится атомарной при обьявлении переменной как volatile. В новой спецификации JSR-133 (в Java5) семантику volatile усилили. На нее наложили правила видимости и правила запрещающие некоторые опитимизации компилятора/jvm.

### Примеры

**Volatile - поможет**

Предположим у нас есть какой-то **неизменяемый обьект**, ссылка на который  доступна для множества потоков, и они постоянно используют его в своих вычилениях. Volatile отлично подходит для данной ситуации. Необходимо, чтобы другие потоки стали использовать новый обьект как только он будет обьявлен (в данном месте имею ввиду, что мы поменяем ссылку с существующего обьекта на сконтруированный новый). При этом нам не требуется специльно синхронизировать это обновление, сбрасывать кеши.

**Volatile - не поможет**

Возьмем обычный счетчик:

```
volatile int counter = 0;

public void update() {
    counter++; //или counter = counter + 1;
}
```

Операция инкремента неатомарна и состоит из трех операций: чтение, инкремент, запись. В данном примере может случиться ситуация, когда:

- Поток1: заходит в метод читает значение "0";
- Поток1: увеличивает значение на единицу "1";
- Выполнение переходит к второму потоку;
- Поток2: чтение значения "0";
- Поток2: увеличение значения на единицу "1";
- Поток2: запись "1" в counter;
- Выполнение переходит к первому потоку;
- Поток1: запись "1" в counter;

В результате вместо значения "2" в счетчике хранится значение "1".
В данном случаче поможет синхронизация метода `update()` или использование `AtomicInteger` и т.д. это уже за пределами данного вопроса.

Подытоживая все вышескзанное - volatile переменные используются, когда все операции происходящие с обьектом "атомарны" как в первом примере (меняется ссылка на полностью сформированный обьект, идет запись из одного одного потока) и **нет конкуренции за состояние обьекта**.

Comment: а где в спеке написано что volatile гарантирует нам атомарность операций? Разве не для того мы ставим synchronize чтобы предотвратить последствия не атомарности? Если бы volatile гарантировал атомарность то он бы один решал все проблемы, так получается или нет?

Comment: Обновил ответ. Вечером попробую привести пример кода.

Comment: **1.** а смысл делать константу Volatile если переменная неизменяемая ну и пусть потоки ее кэшируют какие тут могут возникнуть проблемы? Финальные примитивы и так потокобезопасны зачем ограничивать производительность добавляя Volatile и запрещая потокам кэшировать константу. К кэшу своему то они побыстрее сходят чем в память? Или возможно я не правильно понял что вы имели в виду под "неизеняемым объектом" ....

Comment: **2.**Если во втором примере добавить синхронизацию то и без Volatile будет работать, тут получается он вообще не нужен с точки зрения утечек, хотя полечить падение производительности от False Sharing вполне пригодиться. Правильно говорю? Или запутался?

Comment: 1. Самый просто пример, который могу привести. Представьте что этот общий обьект это набор констант для расчета конвертации из одной валюты в другую при этом иммет такой вид: volatile const = { final rateUsd, final rateEur ... }. Получается, что сами константы final, а сам обьект нет. Если я заменю этот обьект, то некоторые потоки могут испольовать ссылку на новый обьект, а другие на старый. Помечая volatile JMM мне гарантирует, что все потоки при следующем запросе должны увидеть новое значение.

Comment: **2** да Вы правы если сделать синхронизированный блок, то будет все хорошо и можно убрать volatile. Но False Sharing 'га здесь не будет ибо это доступ к **разным переменным** на одной кеш линии. Здесь получается наоборот True Sharing

Answer (score 19):

Напишу пару уточнений.

Насколько понимаю, сам вопрос звучит немного по-другому: "если протокол согласованности кэшей (cache coherency) обязывает кэши процессора хранить ячейку памяти в согласованном состоянии, то зачем нужен volatile, который делает то же самое?"

Во-первых, тут идет обсуждение двух разных уровней. JLS действует внутри JVM, протокол cache coherence присутствует только в специфичной процессорной архитектуре. **Cache coherence не обязан существовать на той архитектуре, для которой скомпилирована и на которой запускается JVM**, таким образом JLS делает опциональную фичу обязательной (на самом деле, фича чуть больше чем просто согласованность, про это ниже). Я практически уверен, что 99%+ многоядерных процессоров сейчас имеют этот протокол, однако Java не может полагаться на что-то, чему нет гарантии - предполагается, что все приложения на Java должны исполняться одинаково на всех архитектурах (кроме случаев взаимодействия с ОС, где могут быть, например, разные пути). Поэтому JLS был практически обязан ввести такое понятие, даже если оно существует на большинстве систем из коробки, потому что даже если JVM реализована на каком-нибудь питоне, она все равно должна исполнять код так же, как и на любой другой системе.

Во-вторых, если взять определение из википедии:

> a multiprocessor is cache consistent if all writes to the same memory location are performed in some sequential order
>
> <sub>(вольный перевод) многопроцессорный кэш является консистентным, если все операции записи по одному адресу выполняется в каком-либо последовательном порядке</sub>

то здесь стоит обратить внимание на "memory location". В Java присутствуют типы данных, которые могут занимать больше одного слова, которым оперирует процессор - как минимум, при запуске на 32битной операционной системе double и long будут занимать по два слова. ***Если*** я все правильно понимаю, то на такой системе может возникнуть следующая ситуация:

```
линия кэша 1: <другие данные><старшие или младшие 32 бита double>
линия кэша 2: <остаток double><другие данные>
```

В этом случае процессор даже в условиях строгого cache coherence имеет право обновить ровно половину double, в результате чего потоки имеют право увидеть мусор вместо реального значения. Volatile запрещает такую ситуацию, гарантируя атомарность записи любой переменной.

В-третьих, кроме непосредственно "железных" проблем, в выполнении кода (косвенно) участвует компилятор. Я не знаю, насколько это применимо к современной Java, но агрессивный компилятор имеет право применить следующие оптимизации:

```
boolean flag = true;

while (flag) {
    doProcessing();
}

// хм, flag не отмечен volatile, значит, программист считает, что он может обновляться только локально
// закэширую-ка я его в регистре процессора, так будет быстрее

eax = load(flag);
while (eax) {
   doProcessing();
}
```

регистр при этом никогда не обновится - он никак не связан с  протоколом целостности кэша. Повторюсь, что я не знаю, как *реально* ведут себя существующие компиляторы Java, но именно этот пример [приведен](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.3) в JLS как небезопасный.

Ну и, наконец, семантика volatile вмешивается в порядок выполнения программы. JLS требует выполнения следующих условий:

- Все действия внутри одного треда имеют зависимость happens-before друг с другом - т.е. результат вышестоящего по коду действия всегда будет виден нижестоящему по коду действию.
- Все действия с volatile имеют зависимость happens-before друг к другу - если кто-то записал в volatile-поле некоторое значение, все последующие чтения уже не имеют право увидеть устаревшее значение
- Отношение happens-before транзитивно, т.е. если операция A happens-before B, а B happens-before C, то справедливо A happens-before C - значит, C увидит все изменения, сделанные A.

Компилятор, JVM и процессор имеют право как угодно перемещать выражения, пока эти условия выполняются. Если взять следующий код

```
int result = 0;
boolean done = false;

....

this.result = 1;
this.done = true;
```

то он имеет полное право превратиться в

```
this.done = true;
this.result = 1;
```

потому что все последующие выражения все равно увидят тот же самый результат. В этом примере другой поток, увидевший `done = true`, все еще может прочитать 0 из `result`. Однако если объявить `done` как volatile, то запись в `result` обязана произойти до записи `true` в `done`, а чтение `true` - после его записи, и таким образом можно обеспечить гарантию видимости изменения в потоках-слушателях. **Это не отменяет возможности того, что в result за этот период произойдет больше одной записи, только гарантирует то, что к моменту чтения из result в нем будет современное обновлению done или более позднее значение.**

#### Обновление

Кроме всего вышеописанного, есть еще один забавный кейс. Java откровенно страдает от хипов большого размера, точнее, от времени выполнения GC на таком хипе. Естественно, с этой проблемой пытаются бороться - с помощью GC, работающих в параллель с приложением. Одной из тактик в таком случае является эвакуация живых объектов из очищаемого региона, чтобы затем просто объявить его свободным для полной перезаписи. В этом случае в JVM одновременно могут жить две копии объекта (одна по старому адресу, и еще одна - эвакуируемая), которые требуют сихронизации записей и чтения. К счастью для имплементаторов, JMM ничего не обещает для обычных чтений, поэтому большинство операций можно освободить от синхронизации, и в один момент может сложиться ситуация, что **все записи идут в один объект, а чтение производится из другого** - до тех пор, пока доступ не синхронизован. Это, как и все вышеописанные примеры, находится в полном согласии с cache coherence, но допускает аномалии при работе приложения (и все по тем же причинам - cache coherence работает на уровне отдельных блоков памяти, JVM - объектов и полей). Этот абзац относится к Shenandoah GC, который ожидается в десятой джаве, но такие способы прострелить ногу можно смело ждать и в других ситуациях.

Comment: Аббревиатура JLS врывается в текст так внезапно. Можно расшифровку и определение?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Java Language Specification, свод правил и условий, по которым должна работать программа на Java

Comment: @etki Спасибо за ответ, и то что более точно сформулировали вопрос, я именно это и пытался спросить. Вы пишите: "регистр при этом никогда не обновится" а не могли бы чуть раскрыть понятие регистра. Просто это совсем новая деталь в рассуждении. Я думал что есть несколько уровней кэша и все а тут на сцену вышел "регистр". Не расскажите немного, что за зверь?

Comment: @Pavel у процессора есть своя зона хранения данных, которая необходима для оперирования данными - это регистры. Если объяснять совсем грубо, то процессору надо где-то хранить промежуточные данные и складывать результаты вычисления, и оперативную память он использовать для этого не может, потому что это замедлило бы скорость вычисления на порядки. Поэтому у каждого ядра есть свое небольшое хранилище, представленное регистрами, каждый из которых может содержать одно процессорное слово. Самый простой пример использования регистра - хранение аргумента и/или результата операции сложения.

Comment: @etki то есть в кэш попадают уже вычисленные значения а результаты промежуточных вычислений процессор складывает в регистры, и токо когда вычисление закончено результат попадает в кэш. Правильно понял?

Comment: @Pavel не совсем, регистры могут использоваться программистом по своему усмотрению, и в память отправляются / читаются из памяти только те вещи, которые открыто записываются / запрашиваются инструкциями. Просто некоторые процессорные инструкции, в том числе упомянутое сложение, читает/пишет из/в строго заданные регистры.

Comment: Вот блин, я не успел награду выдать.

Answer (score 4):

Про false sharing очень правильно выше написали.

А вообще, есть простое правило, если есть один писатель и много читателей, volatile подходит идеально.

Если писателей много, нужны атомарные операции или иные синхронизирующие примитивы.

Comment: «Есть простое правило, если есть один писатель и много читателей, volatile подходит идеально» — ну это в случае, если у вас примитивная структура данных, наподобие одного флага. Если у вас есть _два_ volatile-флага, уже всё плохо.

Comment: Лайк, потому что естественно, Вы правы :)

Аналогично с атомарными операциями.

Comment: @Akzhan Abdulin Спасибо за интересное замечание. Но хотелось бы поддержать  VladD в том что да с примитивами все таки проще, настоящий ад начинаются с сложными объектами обладающими глубокой древовидной структурой...