# Кэш третьего уровная и volatile

Tags: java, многопоточность

Как я знал что volatile это обеспечение синхронизации переменной между кэшами процессорами, уведомляя каждое ядро перед началом изменения и после окончания изменения, какую роль здесь играет кэш третьего уровная, как я читал что он может использоваться как буфер для синхронизации данных, значит ли что volatile переменная хранится в кэше третьего уровня, а значит что чуть чуть медленнее?

Comment: Нет, не значит. Реализация волатильности переменных на уровне виртуальной машины не зависит от особенностей аппаратной реализации.

Comment: Само по себе слово volatile не говорит вообще ничего про кеши. Оно гарантирует что изменения одного потока, будут видимы другому потоку + некоторые ограничения reordering'а процессора. А от чего оно спасает - кеширвоание в процессоре, потоке, или еще где либо - это уже проблема не Java а конкретной реализации Java машины. А вот ответ где будет храниться volatile в конкретной реализации JVM - вопрос сложный.

Comment: Судя по всему, третий уровень уже и вовсе не блокируют https://stackoverflow.com/a/28156150/2908793

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> значит ли что volatile переменная хранится в кэше третьего уровня, а значит что чуть чуть медленнее?

Нет. Прямой зависимости между volatile переменной и кешем третьего уровня - нет.

Как уже заметили выше, ключевое слово volatile гарантирует, что изменения переменной в одном потоке будут видны остальным потокам из-за правил happens before. [Подробнее тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/692793/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-volatile-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-true-false-sharing/693418#693418)

С кешами L1, L2, L3 работает только сам процессор. Он сам решает какие данные подгружать. У нас нет доступа к кешу процессора ни через С ни через ассемблер (поправьте меня в комментариях, если я не прав) [Подробнее на вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%8D%D1%88_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B).

Теоретически при частом обращении к одной и тоже переменной процессор может положить ее в кеш, но мы не можем гарантировать это на 100%

P.S:

- про низкоуровневую работу volatile [Habr](https://habrahabr.ru/post/209128/)
- про синхронизацию кешей процессора [Habr](https://habrahabr.ru/company/intel/blog/143446/)

Comment: Доступ к кэшам весьма системозависим, но практически везде, обладая нужными привилегиями (на уровне ядра, гипервизора и т.п.) мы можем по крайней мере сбросить (invalidate) линию кэша (с синхронизацией  с более нижним уровнем либо без нее).

Comment: Про инвалидавию кешей нашёл такую информацию (для линукса и С) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22701352/how-to-flush-the-cpu-cache-for-a-region-of-address-space-in-linux